# Validation rule on File Sharing button

Tags: apex, before-trigger, files

I am trying to add a validation rule on File Sharing button through an Apex trigger. The trigger is working fine when a user is trying to share the file with any other User. But it is also stopping the users to insert a new file in to the system. Can someone let me know how to handle this issue.

Apex code:

> Apex Class:

```
public static void insertContentDocumentLink(List<ContentDocumentLink> links,Map<Id,ContentDocumentLink> newMap){


    CustomSettings__c cs = CustomSettings__c.getInstance();
    if(cs.Disable_ContentDocumentLink_code_Insert__c){
        return;
    }

    // Strings to store profile names excluded from validation for all objects
    List<String> profileNames = cs.File_Insertion_access_profiles__c != null 
                                ? cs.File_Insertion_access_profiles__c.split(';') : new List<String>{};

    List<Profile> profilesInfo = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Id=:userinfo.getProfileId() LIMIT 1];

    List<Id> contactIds = new List<Id>();
    for(Contact )

    String loggedInProfile = profilesInfo[0].Name;


    for(ContentDocumentLink link: links){

            if(!(profileNames.contains(loggedInProfile))){
                link.addError(cs.File_Sharing_error_message__c, false);
            }

    }

}
```

"

> Apex Trigger: Trigger fires on beforeInsert call

```
public void onBeforeInsert(List<ContentDocumentLink> newcontentDocLink,Map<Id,ContentDocumentLink> newMap)
{

        ContentDocumentLinkActions.insertContentDocumentLink(newcontentDocLink,newMap);
}
```

Comment: That can't be your production code, can it? There's half a `for` loop in there.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a `ContentVersion` - a newly-uploaded file - creates an associated `ContentDocument` record as its parent, and subsequently a `ContentDocumentLink` record to share the file to the location where it was uploaded (such as an Account or a Contact) and a second `ContentDocumentLink` sharing the file to its owner.

Hence, the action of sharing a file and uploading a file actually involve the same data modifications. Your trigger will therefore have to adopt some more sophisticated heuristics to determine which action constitutes a share and which is an upload.

One approach you could take, if it suits your business requirements, is counting `ContentDocumentLink` records for a given `ContentDocument`. When a file is first inserted, it gets two `ContentDocumentLink` records inserted: perhaps you wish to block only those `ContentDocumentLink`s beyond the first two created?